# How do I check the data type for each char in a string?

Tags: c#

*I'm new to C# so expect some mistakes ahead. Any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated.*

I want to limit the accepted inputs for a string to just:

- a-z
- A-Z
- hyphen
- Period

If the character is a letter, a hyphen, or period, it's to be accepted. Anything else will return an error.

The code I have so far is

```
string foo = "Hello!";
foreach (char c in foo)
{
    /*  Is there a similar way
        To do this in C# as 
        I am basing the following
        Off of my Python 3 knowledge
    */

    if (c.IsLetter == true) // *Q: Can I cut out the == true part ?*
    {
        // Do what I want with letters
    }
    else if (c.IsDigit == true)
    {
        // Do what I want with numbers
    }
    else if (c.Isletter == "-") // Hyphen | If there's an 'or', include period as well
    {
        // Do what I want with symbols
    }
}
```

I know that's a pretty poor set of code.

I had a thought whilst writing this: 
Is it possible to create a list of the allowed characters and check the variable against that?

Something like:

```
foreach (char c in foo)
{
    if (c != list)
    {
        // Unaccepted message here
    }
    else if (c == list)
    {
        // Accepted
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at regular expressions

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `== true`.  Also you want `c == '-'` to test for a hyphen.  And if you have a `List<char> list` you would check it like `if(list.Contains(c))` in a `foreach` or just `if(foo.Any(c => !list.Contains(c)))` to test for invalid `foo`.

Comment: `if (c.IsLetter || c.IsDigit || c == '.' || c == '-') { then its OK }` You can remove the `== true` parts since `IsLetter` or `IsDigit` already evalutate to true or false.

Comment: Use a Regex`? Much easier than this

Comment: Unless you specifically want to iterate over the characters as a coding exercise, use a regex.  `[a-zA-Z-\.]*`

Comment: Also note that `char.IsLetter` will match unicode letters outside of the A-Z range.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's appreciated greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single line with regular expressions:

```
Regex.IsMatch(myInput, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*$")
```

```
^                 -> match start of input
[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]   -> match any of a-z , A-Z , 0-9, . or -
               *  -> 0 or more times (you may prefer + which is 1 or more times)
$                 -> match the end of input
```

Comment: Hi spender, thanks for explaining this simply :)
I have generated this code but it returns _no match_ every time and I can't see why
`code
string foo = "Hello!";

            foreach (char c in foo)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(foo, @"^[a-zA-z0-9\.\-]*$"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("match");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no match");
                }
            }`

-- http://pastebin.com/Zns6aWmW

Comment: @bfleuty : this regex will check the entire string for a match, not each char. Your code is checking to see if the string `Hello!` is legal (it isn't) an amount of times equal to the number of characters in `Hello!`.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Easily accomplished with a `Regex`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var isOk = Regex.IsMatch(foo, @"^[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+$");
```

Rundown:

```
match from the start
|              set of possible matches
|              |
|+-------------+
||             |any number of matches is ok
||             ||match until the end of the string
||             |||
vv             vvv
^[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+$ 
  ^  ^  ^  ^ ^
  |  |  |  | |
  |  |  |  | match dot
  |  |  |  match hyphen
  |  |  match 0 to 9
  |  match a-z (lowercase)
  match A-Z (uppercase)
```

Comment: Vertical art is better than horizontal ( /hug @spender ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.IsMatch function and specify your regular expression.

Or define manually chars what you need. Something like this:

```
        string foo = "Hello!";

        char[] availableSymbols = {'-', ',', '!'};
        char[] availableLetters = {'A', 'a', 'H'}; //etc.
        char[] availableNumbers = {'1', '2', '3'}; //etc

        foreach (char c in foo)
        {
            if (availableLetters.Contains(c)) 
            {
                // Do what I want with letters
            }
            else if (availableNumbers.Contains(c))
            {
                // Do what I want with numbers
            }
            else if (availableSymbols.Contains(c))
            {
                // Do what I want with symbols
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solution

You can use the `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(char)` method. It returns the `UnicodeCategory` of a character. The following unicode categories might be what you're look for:

- `UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber`
- `UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter` and `UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter`

An example:

```
string foo = "Hello!";
foreach (char c in foo)
{  
    UnicodeCategory cat = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);

    if (cat == UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter || cat == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
    {
        // Do what I want with letters
    }
    else if (cat == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber)
    {
        // Do what I want with numbers
    }
    else if (c == '-' || c == '.')
    {
        // Do what I want with symbols
    }
}
```

#### Answers to your other questions

**Can I cut out the == true part?:**

Yes, you can cut the `== true` part, it is not required in C#

**If there's an 'or', include period as well.:**

To create or expressions use the 'barbar' (||) operator as i've done in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.IsMatch with "^[a-zA-Z_.]*$" to check for valid characters.

```
string foo = "Hello!";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(foo, "^[a-zA-Z_\.]*$"))
{
  throw new ArgumentException("Exception description here")
}
```

Other than that you can create a list of chars and use string.Contains method to check if it is ok.

```
string validChars = "abcABC./";
foreach (char c in foo)
{
    if (!validChars.Contains(c))
    {
         // Throw exception
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to check for == true/false in if line. Both expressions are equal below

```
if (boolvariable) { /* do something */ }
if (boolvariable == true) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have some kind of collection of similar things, an array, a list, a string of characters, whatever, you'll see at the definition of the collection that it implements IEnumerable

public class String : ..., IEnumerable,

here T is a char. It means that you can ask the class: "give me your first T", "give me your next T", "give me your next T" and so on until there are no more elements.

This is the basis for all **Linq**. Ling has about 40 functions that act upon sequences. And if you need to do something with a sequence of the same kind of items, consider using LINQ.

The functions in LINQ can be found in class Enumerable. One of the function is Contains. You can use it to find out if a sequence contains a character.

char[] allowedChars = "abcdefgh....XYZ.-".ToCharArray();

Now you have a sequence of allowed characters. Suppose you have a character x and want to know if x is allowed:

```
char x = ...;
bool xIsAllowed = allowedChars.Contains(x);
```

Now Suppose you don't have one character x, but a complete string and you want only the characters in this string that are allowed:

```
string str = ...
var allowedInStr = str
    .Where(characterInString => allowedChars.Contains(characterInString));
```

If you are going to do a lot with sequences of things, consider spending some time to familiarize yourself with LINQ:

[Linq explained](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq)